# How to show previous selected value of a uipickerview in ios programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

How to show previously selected value of a UIPickerView in iOS programming

Answer (score 0):

You have to take two variable for it 1) `currentSelectedIndex` 2)`prevSelectedIndex`

And In

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pV didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    prevSelectedIndex = currentSelectedIndex
    currentSelectedIndex = row;
    //your Code...
}
```

now you can use `prevSelectedIndex` to get `pickerDataSourceArray` value which was previously selected.